# URL request integration with microsoft teams

Tags: api, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

It is possible to make a url request by myself to integrate with microsoft teams ?

```
Example : create a url request get To get class named **** name as parameter ..?
```

Or only we can use url request by `microsoft team` in official website ?

Comment: If you’re a team owner, go to the team name and click More options button > Get link to team. Click Copy and send the link to the person you want to invite to your team. That person can simply paste the link into any browser to join the team. Please note that currently, guests can't join a team via a link or code.

Comment: Are you looking from Graph API as well?

Comment: @tino, Did the below responses helped you?

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing for Teams for education, then a 'Class' is the same a a 'Team' in most developer documentation.

in that case to create a hyperlink to a Class / Team , then you can create a [deeplink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links)

Deeplinks are possible to many different entities in teams, a few common ones are:

- deeplink to a team : `https://teams.microsoft.com/l/team/<<teamid>>`
- deeplink to a channel: `https://teams.microsoft.com/l/channel/<<channelId>>`

but it is also possible to navigate directly to a chat or specific app.